# python2.7: Why does printing a list of chinese look like [u'\u4ed6', u'\u6765\u5230', u'\u4e86', u'\u7f51\u6613']?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp

I used the jieba chinese dictionary for word segmentation.
When I print a list of words, the result is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import jieba
import sys
import jieba


s1 = "他来到了网易杭研大厦!"
seg_list = jieba.cut(s1)
lst1 = ", ".join(seg_list)
print lst1
m =lst1.split(', ')
print m[2]
punct = set(u''':!),.:;?]}¢'"、。〉》」』】〕〗〞︰︱︳﹐､﹒﹔﹕﹖﹗﹚﹜﹞！），．：；？｜｝︴︶︸︺︼︾﹀﹂﹄﹏､～￠々‖•·ˇˉ―--′’”([{£¥'"‵〈《「『【〔〖（［｛￡￥〝︵︷︹︻︽︿﹁﹃﹙﹛﹝（｛“‘-—_…''')

filterpuntl = list(filter(lambda x: x not in punct, m))

print filterpuntl[2]
```

The result is following:

```
他, 来到, 了, 网易, 杭研, 大厦, !
[u'\u4ed6', u'\u6765\u5230', u'\u4e86', u'\u7f51\u6613', u'\u676d\u7814', u'\u5927\u53a6', u'!']
[u'\u4ed6', u'\u6765\u5230', u'\u4e86', u'\u7f51\u6613', u'\u676d\u7814', u'\u5927\u53a6']
```

How to change the `[u'\u4ed6', u'\u6765\u5230'  ...]`  to Chinese characters?

When I print a single element of the list, it is Chinese:

```
print m[2]
print filterpuntl[2]
```

The result is:

```
他, 来到, 了, 网易, 杭研, 大厦, !
了
了
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u'\u4ed6'` *is* a Chinese character. It's just a different representation, just like you can write `0.1` or `1e-1` for the same number – it's the same thing, just with different looks.

If you want to see the proper glyphs when printing a list etc. (which emits the `repr()` form of the objects), switch to Python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(['\u4ed6'])
['他']
```